# Will there always be prime numbers of the form $X_i =i^2+i+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, triangular-numbers

The sequence is:

$$1,3,7,13,21,31,...$$

$$ OR $$

$$(1),(1+2),(1+2+4),(1+2+4+6), (1+2+4+6+8), (1+2+4+6+8+...),...$$

$$OR$$

$$X_i =i^2+i+1$$

$$OR$$

$$X_i = 1+2T_i$$

($T$ for triangular numbers)
$$\begin{matrix}
index&Sequence&factorization
\\0&1&
\\1&3&
\\2&7&
\\3&13& 
\\4&21&(3⋅7) **
\\5&31&
\\6&43&
\\7&57&(3⋅19)
\\8&73&
\\9&91&(7⋅13) **
\\10&111&(3⋅37)
\\11&133& (7⋅19)
\\12&157&
\\13&183& (3⋅61)
\\14&211& 
\\15&241&
\\16&273& (13⋅21) **
\\17&307&
\\18&343& (7^3)
\\19&381& (3⋅127)
\\20&421&
\\21&463&
\\22&507&  (3 ⋅13^2)
\\23&553& (7 ⋅79)
\\24&601&
\\25&651& (21⋅31) **
\\26&703& (19⋅37) 
\\.&.&.
\\.&.&.
\\.&.&.
\end{matrix}$$

Let's say $X_i$ is a number in the sequence ($i$ for index) and its prime factors are $x_a$, then any $x_a$ will appear as a  prime factor  in  $X_{i+x_a}$.

Once "introduced" the prime factors $x_a$ repeat themselves $x_a$ times, but they do get "introduced"  more than once.

There is also the pattern that if $i$ is a square number such as $X_4 = X_1⋅X_2$, $X_9 = X_2⋅X_3$, $X_{16} = X_3⋅X_4$

Since every factor is "introduced" more than one, I was wondering, the following:

The subset in question is: $1,3,7,13,31,43,73,157,211,241,307,421,463,601,...$

These are the numbers that do not have factors that were "introduced" earlier.

Are these number always prime numbers (except $1$)? and will they continue for ever?

Comment: Whether there exists $any$ quadratic $F$ such that $F(n)$ is prime for infinitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ is an unsolved problem

Comment: See OEIS [A002383](https://oeis.org/A002383) for more references.

Comment: See the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture). Most all instances of this are out of reach with current knowledge.

Comment: @dxiv I have checked the sequence but with 1 at the beginning and it didn’t show, I see it now, and I get the conjecture.

Comment: What do you mean with "always" ? I only see one parameter, namely $i$. Probably there are infinite many primes of the form $i^2+i+1$ , but this is , as mentioned , only a conjecture.

Comment: Isaac, I think I am getting there. Evidently you are going to discard $19 \cdot 37,$  despite the fact that neither can be expressed as $u^2 + u + 1.$  But $19, 37$   show up as factors of $57$   and $111$